# node.js - reading child process stdout 100 bytes at a time

Tags: node.js, stream, child-process

I'm spawning a child that produces lots of data (I'm using 'ls -lR /' here as an example). I want to asynchronously read the child's stdout 100 bytes at a time.

> So I want to do: get100().then(process100).then(get100).then(process100).then(...

For some reason, this code only loops 3 times and I stop getting Readable events. I can't figure out why?

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var spawn   = require("child_process").spawn;

var exec = spawn( "ls", [ "-lR", "/"] );  

var get100 = function () {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       var tryTransfer = function() {
          var block = exec.stdout.read(100);
          if (block) {
            console.log("Got 100 Bytes");
            exec.stdout.removeAllListeners('readable');  
            resolve();
          } else console.log("Read Failed - not enough bytes?");
        };
        exec.stdout.on('readable', tryTransfer);
    });
};

var forEver = Promise.method(function(action) {
    return action().then(forEver.bind(null, action));
});

forEver(
    function() { return get100(); }
)
```

Comment: This seems to be a very convoluted way to do a simple `ls`. What are trying to do? What do you do with the 100 bytes you're reading?

Comment: I'm not really running ls. I'm running some proprietary .exe which generates a ton of data. I have a list of consumers. I need to get the first 100 bytes, add a header, and send it to the first consumer, the next 100 + header to the second consumer, etc. I'm trying to do this asynchronously.

Comment: I see, since exec.stdout is a stream, you can stick to streams. I'm writing an anwser.

Comment: I think I figured out at least part of the problem. I think that the "readable" event is sent for some number of bytes that have arrived in the buffer. Until we read this number of bytes, we will not get another event even if more bytes arrive.

Comment: According to the doc, `readable` is fired when a chunk of data is available, whatever its size is. I think the issue might be the input stream is read too fast and there is a moment when 100 bytes are not available so your processing just stops. How big/huge is the output from the .exe? Storing it in a file and processing that file might be a solution, you'll have more control. Like I said below, streaming/processing a giant 2GB csv file is no issue for nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`event-stream`](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream), you can *emit* 100 bytes data from the spawned process as long as there is data to read (streams are async):

```
var es = require('event-stream');
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var exec = spawn("ls", ["-lR", "/"]);

var stream = es.readable(function (count, next) {
    // read 100 bytes
    while (block = exec.stdout.read(100)) {
        // if you have tons of data, it's not a good idea to log here
        // console.log("Got 100 Bytes");
        // emit the block
        this.emit('data', block.toString()); // block is a buffer (bytes array), you may need toString() or not
    }

    // no more data left to read
    this.emit('end');
    next();
}).on('data', function(data) {
    // data is the 100 bytes block, do what you want here

    // the stream is pausable and resumable at will
    stream.pause();
    doStuff(data, function() {
        stream.resume();
    });
});
```

Comment: if I understand this correctly, the stream will be read as quickly as possible and be translated to calls to doStuff(data). So if doStuff is not keeping up, won't the process eventually run out of memory?

Comment: Tried running this code as is. doStuff is never called?

Comment: @GroovyDotCom, yes it streams as fast as possible but you can pause the input stream if needed (I'm editing the answer to add an example). `doStuff()` never called? That's weird, I tried with a simple console.log and I get the long output from `ls` splitted by 100 bytes: https://tonicdev.com/shanshan/streamed-stdout

Comment: are the results on tonicdev a full run? If so then there is a problem because no way is your ls -lR / only 34 * 3 * 100 bytes = 10,000

Comment: I switched from ls to:  var exec = spawn("hexdump", ["/dev/urandom"]);
and read 1 byte at a time. It reads 65536 bytes before it stops. That number is not a coincidence! Something is up.

Comment: @GroovyDotCom TonicDev must have some sort of limit on the output, it's a free tool. I tried on Cloud9 and the limit is more random (between 8000 and 11000 when I tested). About your second test, that gives exactly 64Kb, it's seems to be some sort of limit somewhere, but not on streams I think (I already streamed a 2GB csv file with no issue).