# NodeJS Child Process stdout is not live but works fine when the command is executed in terminal

Tags: node.js

I am executing a command and listening to its stdout using `spawn` like below

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const childProcess = spawn('RV', ["...jpg"]);

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
})

child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log("error", data.toString());
})
child.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("Error", err);
})
child.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
  console.log("Child process exited")
});
```

Child process stdout is not live. If i close the child process, it prints the remaining stdout.  I understand this is because the stdout is buffered till it receives a new line.

[Nodejs always cann't capture child process's stdout data completely, unless child process fllush(stdout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281500/nodejs-always-cannt-capture-child-processs-stdout-data-completely-unless-chil)

But if i execute the same command in terminal, it just shows all the stdout logs without the need to close the subprocess.  If this is an issue with the application i am calling then it shouldn't work with terminal right?

Is there an option in nodejs's childprocess to execute the command just like executing in terminal?

Comment: Take a look at https://nodejs.org/docs/v8.1.4/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: Switch to reading by bytes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971616/node-js-reading-child-process-stdout-100-bytes-at-a-time